# Eclipse Gradle Integration Error - Installing software has encouraged

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle

I get this error while I try to install Gradle on Eclipse. I tried with this link:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-0

The error message is as follow. Can anyone helo.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core,3.6.3.201411271013-RELEASE.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1990886222537489997.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1990886222537489997.jar
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.feature,3.6.3.201411271013-RELEASE.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1754777427947047028.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1754777427947047028.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.toolingapi,3.6.3.201411271013-RELEASE.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile833353327458962376.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile833353327458962376.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui,3.6.3.201411271013-RELEASE.
```

Comment: Would the gradle (or gradle wrapper) command line get you by for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has another project called **Buildship: Eclipse Plug-ins for Gradle** which appears to be working.

http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship/downloads

I was able to install this into Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse/Mars) by the following process.

> Help > Install New Software > Add

Name: Buildship
Location: http://download.eclipse.org/buildship/updates/e45/releases

> OK

From there I selected the "Buildship" repository and installed "Eclipse Plug-ins for Gradle" without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry to say this, but Eclipse is not supported anymore.

Google just made an own IDE on IntelliJ.

https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

It has everything built-in and its way better than eclipse!

**EDIT**: With everything, i'm talking about gradle, maven, better SDK support, better virtual device support, etc.

**EDIT2**: Before i forget... you can even import your eclipse project.